# Drop rows of df with fewer entries

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working currently with pandas in python.

I've got a dataset of customers (user_id on column1) and of the item they bought (column2).

Example dataset:

| ID_user | ID_item |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

Now I want only to focus on customers, which have bought more than 10 items. How can I create a new dataframe with pandas and drop all other customers with less than 10 items bought?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could first group your dataframe by the column "ID_user" and the `.count()` method. Afterwards filter out only those values that are bigger 10 with a `lambda function`.

```
# Group by column ID_user and the method .count()
df = df.groupby('ID_user').count()
# Only show values for which the lambda function evaluates to True
df = df[lambda row: row["ID_item"] > 10]
```

Or just do it in one line:

```
df = df.groupby('ID_user').count()[lambda row: row["ID_item"] > 10]
```

Comment: Passing functions as indexes? I never knew you could do that! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can try `groupby` with `transform` then filter it

```
n = 10
cond = df.groupby('ID_user')['ID_item'].transform('sum')
out = df[cond>=n].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `groupby` + `filter` will do the job:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID_user').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 10)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID_user, ID_item]
Index: []
```

Now, in your example, there aren't actually any groups that do have more than 10 items, so it's showing an empty dataframe here. But in your real data, this would work.

Comment: The pandas documentation says "Note that this routine does not filter a dataframe on its contents. The filter is applied to the labels of the index." So I was wondering if this also works on the items, which should be considered as "content" right?

Comment: I'm sorry @Carst3n, for some reason, I'm having trouble understanding you. What's your point?

Comment: I thought that this filter would only be applied to the labels of each column. For example, it would allow us to filter out column labels based on a string and that this would no be used to filter out the actual values within a column. However, this is quite new to me so i might not have fully understood this method.

Comment: @Carst3n - This is the [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) method of a `DataFrameGroupBy` object, It's different from `DataFrame.filter`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Thank you! This is where i went wrong. :)